# validating string against special character except comma

Tags: java, regex

I have been trying to validate string against special characters except comma.

This is what I have done:

```
        if (str.matches("[A-Z0-9, ]*")) 
               System.out.println("Special char present");
```

But it is not working properly.How to fix this?

Comment: Define _not working properly_.

Comment: What strings are you testing it against? And which are or aren't working, and why? If your problem is with lowercase letters, you need to add those to the class as well `"[A-Za-z0-9, ]*"`.

Comment: what is your definition of a special character?

Comment: Are lowercase characters also considered special?

Comment: My string should consist of only uppercase letters, digits and comma.But when I try to test it by passing semicolon it doesnot print the line

Comment: It can consist of whitespace as well

Comment: @user3505394 the semi-colon isnt included in the character class so its working correctly

Comment: And which strings are you using which should or shouldn't work, and give the opposite result?

Comment: No, I mean it should not accept special characters like ;

Comment: If I pass ABC ;JHK,HJK it should not accept it and print Special char present

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you forgot to negate your condition since now it just checks if string contains only `A-Z` `0-9` `,` . If you want opposite condition try with

```
if (!str.matches("[A-Z0-9, ]*")) 
//  ^- add this exclamation mark which represents negation
    System.out.println("Special char present");
```

Comment: Also make that [A-Za-z0-9, ]*

Comment: @AlexandruSeverin From what OP said in comments "My string should consist of only uppercase letters, digits and comma... It can consist of whitespace as well" I don't see need for lowercase characters.