# How to Remove Special Character Except Comma

Tags: java

I have an Output in my Android EditText like below :

`["HOT","SMALL"]`

I want my Output like below :

`HOT,SMALL`

I want to remove `[]` and `""` but not the Comma `,` . I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23412070/validating-string-against-special-character-except-comma) but its not work. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23412070/validating-string-against-special-character-except-comma) but this one remove all Special Chars. Anybody can help my problem, any suggest will helpfull for me. Thanks Before.

Comment: Can you show us what and how your outputing in edittext, may be it can be solved without help of regex or replaceAll.

Comment: I getText an JSONArray `[VALUE, VALUE, ........nVALUE]` where `VALUE` is item that user clicked, So the `VALUE` is have nLength.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways I'd do this.

The first, quick and straight forward is to just replace all the special characters with `""`, using a regex and [`String.replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

```
myString.replaceAll("[\\\"\\[\\]]", "");
```

(Btw, I used http://rubular.com/ as a quick way to check my regex. Remember that the regex needs to be escaped for java - I used [this tool](http://www.freeformatter.com/java-dotnet-escape.html#ad-output) to do that.)

The alternative is that you're actually looking at the String representation of a JSON object here, so convert the JSON string into a Java array of Strings using something like [`org.json`](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/), and then concatenate the strings together with a `,` delimiter.

Comment: The Comma is gone too @dwjohnston

Comment: Sorry @dwjohnston my fault, I forgot to remove `.replace(",", "")` . Its work perfect thanks for your answer